# Same subscription inside another one with RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

In function of the reponse, I need to call another time the same service with Subscriptions.

For example:

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(
  result => {
    if (result.length == 0) {
      this.service.getData().subscribe(...);
    }
  }
);
```

I need to subsribe again when I button is clicked:

```
onClick() {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(...);
}
```

I think, this is not a good way. I would be subscribing three times.

How Can I resolve this problem correctly?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap()` in your case.

```
this.service.getData().pipe(
    switchMap(data => {
        // work with 'data'
        if (data.length === 0) {
            return this.service.getData();
        }
        return of(undefined);
    }),
).subscribe(result => {
    // work with 'result'
});
```

Maybe in your case you could use `retry()` if you want to send the same request again if the first one returned an error.

Docs about `retry()`: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/retry

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you put the *get data* logic inside a method, which you can reuse. I've used [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) that allows you to chain observables, and [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html) that just creates an observable filled with a data.

```js
class MyService {
  ...

  getData() {
    return this.service.getData().pipe(
      switchMap(data => {
        return data.length > 0 ? of(data) : this.getData();
      })
    );
  }

  onClick() {
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```